# TrimEnd for Java?

Tags: java, string

In the process of converting a C# application to Java, I came across the use of String's `TrimEnd` method. Is there an equivalent Java implementation? I can't seem to find one.

I'd rather not replace it with `trim`, since I don't want to change the meaning or operation of the program at this point unless I have to.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Since Java 11, you can use ["string".stripTrailing()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#stripTrailing()) to strip off trailing whitespace, or ["string".stripLeading()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#stripLeading()). If you need the more generic version that strips off the specified characters, then see below, there is no direct replacement in Java 11.

Leaving the old answer here for pre-Java 11 versions:

There is no direct equivalent, however if you want to strip trailing whitespace you can use:

```
"string".replaceAll("\\s+$", "");
```

`\s` is the regular expression character set "whitespace", if you only care about stripping trailing spaces, you can replace it with the space character. If you want to use the more general form of [trimEnd()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend.aspx), that is to remove an arbitrary set of trailing characters then you need to modify it slightly to use:

```
"string".replaceAll("[" + characters + "]+$", "");
```

Do be aware that the first argument is a generic regex, and so if one of your `characters` is the `]` then this needs to be the first character in your list. For a full description of the java regex patterns, look at [the javadoc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Should you ever need to implement the [trimstart()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart.aspx) method from .net, it is almost the same, but would look like this:

```
"string".replaceAll("^[" + characters + "]+", "");
```

Comment: @finnw: You are correct… the regex needs to be anchored. Thanks for catching that for me, I have updated the answer to put in the correct regex.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to get back to this. Thanks for the great answer! I just had to make one small correction. '"\s+$"' needs an extra '`' to properly escape it.

Answer (score 13):

There isn't a direct replacement. You can use regexps, or perhaps Commons Lang [StringUtils.stripEnd()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#stripEnd-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) method.

Comment: +1 for StringUtils. In addition to trimXXX, they also offer stripXXX, which properly handles Unicode whitespace (trim only/also trims ASCII control codes).

Answer (score 7):

**Good news!**
It was added in Java 11.
[[JDK-8200378] String::strip, String::stripLeading, String::stripTrailing - Java Bug System](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8200378)

- `strip()`
- `stripLeading()`
- `stripTrailing()`

Comment: Still limited; in C# you can give that a list of chars to trim as argument.

Answer (score 6):

if you value performance (perhaps your method is used in a loop over thousands of strings), than you could use this method:

```
public String trimEnd(String value) {
    int len = value.length();
    int st = 0;
    while ((st < len) && value.charAt(len - 1) == ' ') {
      len--;
    }
    return value.substring(0, len);
}
```

Comment: If you also have tabs and other whitespace, replace `... == ' '` with [`Character.isWhitespace(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace%28char%29).

Answer (score 4):

There is no native equivalent. Use this:

```
public static String trimEnd( String s,  String suffix) {

 if (s.endsWith(suffix)) {

   return s.substring(0, s.length() - suffix.length());

 }
 return s;
}
```

Comment: you should check in a loop. It is possible that suffix is at the end twice or more.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a trick to do it from:
http://www.overclock.net/coding-programming/320937-simple-java-trim-help.html

```
str = str.replaceAll(" +$", "");
```

Comment: Note this trims trailing spaces.  @Paul Wagland's variation trims trailing whitespace characters.  The C# method uses an array of "trimChars".

Answer (score 0):

If performance is not important one-liner could be used:

```
("X" + str).trim().substring(1)
```

Comment: is this removing characters from end of string?

Answer (score 0):

I like googles version from guava.

```
import static com.google.common.base.CharMatcher.WHITESPACE;

WHITESPACE.trimTrailingFrom(value);
```

or

```
CharMatcher.anyOf(suffix).trimTrailingFrom(value);
```

if you are using maven you can add it simply to your dependencies section of pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>23.0</version>
</dependency>
```